# QBO V3 Behavior order of operations

Tags: javascript

I'm running into a problem creating a "depends" behavior where the object to depend on is an `<option/>` tag that has not loaded up yet because it loads up via an ajax call.  There appears to be a race condition where the depends behavior is trying to load up before the ajax call is complete.  Here is the element markup that failing to load the depends behavior:

```
<div class="control-group" data-behavior="Depend" data-depend-options="{{'depends': 'W9', 'required': true}}">
```

"W9" will be the ID of the `<option/>` tag.  This option tag will be loaded up by the following code:

```
<select name="ProfessionalLicenseType" id="ProfessionalLicenseType" class="required" data-behavior="Dropdown" data-dropdown-options="{{ 'type': 'ObjectType', 'data': {{ 'Object': 'ProfessionalLicense' }}, 'selected': '{AttachmentType}', 'id': 'ObjectType' }}">
```

Should I not use the HTML markup to create the dependency behavior?  Should I instead try to use javascript to create this dependency?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Depend behavior support binding to a select tag's value, rather than an option tag:

```
<div class="control-group" data-behavior="Depend" data-depend-options="{{'depends': 'ProfessionalLicenseType=W9', 'required': true}}">
```

The Depend behavior, on initialization, will check the value of ProfessionalLicenseType, and find that it's empty, disabling/hiding your dependent div tag. It will also add a change event handler to the ProfessionalLicenseType dropdown (qbo.Depends.js line 45):

```
source.addEvent('change', qbo3.dependencyCheck.pass([source, element, options, depends]));
```

The Dropdown behavior will later (asynchronously) load your options via AJAX, and if the behavior's options.selected is set, will set the matching option.selected=true (qbo.Dropdown.js line 105):

```
if ((row[value] || row) == options.selected) {
  target.options[target.options.length - 1].selected = true;
  target.defaultIndex = target.options.length - 1;
  target.fireEvent('change');
}
```

The to this working is the `target.fireEvent('change')` noted above; that will trigger the Depend behavior to re-evaluate the dependency and react appropriately.